# Entity splitting with inherited models

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first

I'm trying to use a base model for all standard fields and any other model, such as the LocationIssueModel and PersonIssueModel, will have different properties. The table structure is the same where location_issue will have fields it needs where person_issue will have fields it needs all while the main issue table is used for common fields. Both location_issue and person_issue have a PK that is a FK to issue_ky on the issue table.

Using the below configuration and trying to do a Linq query and error is thrown on IssueModel1.

Is this configuration correct?

Edit: Due to an interface using the IsActiveLocation flag entity splitting needs to be used

Models

```
public class IssueModel
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string RequestNumber { get; set; }
    public bool IsActiveLocation { get; set; }
}

public class LocationIssueModel : IssueModel
{
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
}

public class PersonIssueModel : IssueModel
{
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<LocationIssueModel>()
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.Properties(t => new { t.Key, t.RequestNumber });
        m.ToTable("issue");
    })
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.Properties(t => new { t.Key, t.LocationName });
        m.ToTable("location_issue");
    });
}
```

SQL

```
SELECT '0X0X' AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[issue_ky] AS [issue_ky], 
[Extent3].[request_nbr] AS [request_nbr],
[Extent1].[location_ky] AS [location_ky], 
FROM     [dbo].[Issue1] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [wm].[location_issue] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[issue_ky] = [Extent2].[issue_ky]
INNER JOIN [wm].[issue] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[issue_ky] = [Extent3].[issue_ky]
```

As you can see the generated sql is not as expected.

Comment: The solution was to use TPT inheritance (as Florian suggested) and entity splitting on the base model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is wrong, if I understand you correctly you want to do table-per-type (TPT) inheritance, which can be done like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<LocationIssueModel>().ToTable("LocationIssues");
    modelBuilder.Entity<PersonIssueModel>().ToTable("PersonIssues");
}
```

Check out this link to read more about this type of inheritance: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt

Comment: Thanks for the help! Made an edit to my original question, but was able to use your solution.